# Can't SlideToggle() class under h2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem**

My problem is that I'm trying to `slideToggle()` a `<div class='inputs'></div>` underneath the `<h2></h2>` that was clicked on. Another thing is that I'm not getting any errors.

```js
    // MAIN
    function main() {
        $(".toggle-inputs").on("click", function() {
           $(this).find('.inputs').slideToggle();
        });
    }
    
    // LOAD
    $(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<section>

    <div class="required">
        <h3>* Required Fields</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="add-student">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Student <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="student-id" placeholder="* Student ID...">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-firstname" placeholder="* Teacher's Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-lastname" placeholder="* Teacher's Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Student</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-STUDENT -->

    <div class="add-teacher">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Teacher <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Teacher</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-TEACHER -->

    <div class="add-driver">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Driver <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Phone Number...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Area Code...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-firstname" placeholder="* Leader's Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-lastname" placeholder="* Leader's Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Driver</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-DRIVER -->

    <div class="add-team">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Team <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Add A Member</a>

            <input type="text" name="student-id" placeholder="* Leader's ID...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Team</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-TEAM -->

</section>
<!-- END OF SECTION -->

</div>
<!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: *Hint:* `.find()` looks at the child elements of `h2` (which is a single `<i>`), not the next elements in the DOM. One way to solve that is get the `.parent()` first.

Comment: The problem is with the `find` which get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Comment: you  could replace `find` with `next('.inputs')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `.find()` is looking at the child elements of `h2` which in this case is only a `<i>` element so it doesn't find what it's looking for. Instead get the parent first so you are searching in `<div class="inputs">` instead.

```js
// MAIN
    function main() {
        $(".toggle-inputs").on("click", function() {
           $(this).parent().find('.inputs').slideToggle();
        });
    }
    
    // LOAD
    $(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<section>

    <div class="required">
        <h3>* Required Fields</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="add-student">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Student <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="student-id" placeholder="* Student ID...">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-firstname" placeholder="* Teacher's Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-lastname" placeholder="* Teacher's Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Student</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-STUDENT -->

    <div class="add-teacher">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Teacher <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Teacher</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-TEACHER -->

    <div class="add-driver">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Driver <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Phone Number...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Area Code...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-firstname" placeholder="* Leader's Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-lastname" placeholder="* Leader's Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Driver</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-DRIVER -->

    <div class="add-team">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Team <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Add A Member</a>

            <input type="text" name="student-id" placeholder="* Leader's ID...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Team</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-TEAM -->

</section>
<!-- END OF SECTION -->

</div>
<!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had to use `next()` instead of `find()`.

```js
    // MAIN
    function main() {
        $(".toggle-inputs").on("click", function() {
           $(this).next('.inputs').slideToggle();
        });
    }
    
    // LOAD
    $(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<section>

    <div class="required">
        <h3>* Required Fields</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="add-student">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Student <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="student-id" placeholder="* Student ID...">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-firstname" placeholder="* Teacher's Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-lastname" placeholder="* Teacher's Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Student</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-STUDENT -->

    <div class="add-teacher">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Teacher <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Teacher</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-TEACHER -->

    <div class="add-driver">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Driver <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Phone Number...">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Area Code...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-firstname" placeholder="* Leader's Firstname...">
            <input type="text" name="teacher-lastname" placeholder="* Leader's Lastname...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Driver</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-DRIVER -->

    <div class="add-team">

        <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Team <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

        <div class="inputs">
            <a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Add A Member</a>

            <input type="text" name="student-id" placeholder="* Leader's ID...">

            <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Team</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF ADD-TEAM -->

</section>
<!-- END OF SECTION -->

</div>
<!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need different selectors for each section. Like;

```
<h2 id="toggle-inputs-students">Add Student
```

And

```
<div id="inputs-students">
```

When it comes to JS part, you can use code below

```
$( "#toggle-inputs-students" ).click(function() {
  $( "#inputs-students" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
// Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: `#` is for id's.